# Is the logo design too minimalistic?

Tags: logo, critique, style-identification

I making this simple logo, but I want to know. Is the logo look too minimalistic to you guys, it need some improvement maybe?[image]

Comment: Thanks for following our critique guidelines. However, "too minimalistic" is a bit opinion based and depends on various factors / use cases. To me, the black on burnt orange is hard to read and the mismatch of thickness of the font and lines of the ball is too great

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks for pointing out the wrong choice of color for the font, but I don't understand what do you mean by "mismatch of thickness of the font  and liness of the ball is too great". Is it that the font size should be reduced, or the object's line that should be increased to make it stand out?

Comment: I think if one knows what Takoyaki is, then it makes sense - I had to look it up. I kind of think this really is more cultural and I'd hesitate to state what is or in not viable because clearly I don't understand the culture of any target audience.

Comment: @Scott Culture would definitely be a problem interpreting that image, From a British perspective it looks a bit like a [Christmas pudding](https://events.onthewight.com/ventnor/events/31049/lb_home/Christmas-Pudding_Colour.jpg?1572873371), which definitely doesn't contain an octopus surprise. The French might think it's [a profiterole](https://www.abakingjourney.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Profiteroles-Feature-1-1024x1024.jpg).

Comment: Thank you guys for your tips, maybe I can do it better for the next one

Comment: I didn't mean font size, I meant line width. The font used doesn't really match the style of the image to me

Comment: Why? Is the font pointy and meed smoothness of font like in Sans serif and make it uncomfortable for customer to see the logo?

Comment: It's the difference between the stroke of the font and the stroke of the line drawings that is mismatched. try making the lines in the drawing thicker.